# I am getting an "unused argument" error when I try to reproduce the ComBat example from the sva package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a batch correction using ComBat from the sva package in R. I basically tried the examples used in the sva documentation from the "bladderbatch" data:

```
library(sva)
library(bladderbatch)
data(bladderdata)
library(pamr)
library(limma)
pheno=pData(bladderEset)
edata=exprs(bladderEset)
batch=pheno$batch
modcombat=model.matrix(~1, data=pheno)
combat.edata=ComBat(dat=edata, batch=batch, mod=modcombat, par.prior=TRUE, prior.plots=FALSE)
```

I however am getting an unused arguments error:

```
Error in ComBat(dat = edata, batch = batch, mod = modcombat, par.prior = TRUE,  : 
  unused arguments (dat = edata, batch = batch, mod = modcombat)
```

I would be grateful for any help as to where I am going wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: eventually https://www.biostars.org/p/209901/

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error on R 4.0.0,`packageVersion('sva') #[1] ‘3.36.0’` and `packageVersion('bladderbatch') #[1] ‘1.26.0’` . I copy-pasted the same code as in your post.

Comment: Hi Ronak, thank you for that. I think something from my workspace was interfering. I tried again by clearing my workspace and it worked!